# Realistic Interior Lighting In Blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, lighting, photorealism

I'm trying to make realistic interiors like this: [image]

or this: [image]

with soft lighting and a lot of bounce/indirect light. Any lighting techniques that would help make renders look like these renders? manual lighting with lamps? or HDR'S?  or both?

Comment: HI. Have you tried the techniques you mention and they aren't working? Can you give specific examples of what you've tried and where you feel like you're falling short? At the minute, just asking for general techniques, this question is quite broad and might be closed.

Comment: I've used HDRS and I can't get that soft lighting with lots of indirect lighting, and lamps are good but I still don't get enough indirect light... do I need more windows?